# TIdHTTP generate many temporary internet files when upload?

Tags: http, file-upload, indy, delphi-2010, temporary-files

I have an application that upload many files on the internet with `TIdHTTP` Indy component.
 Sometimes happen that many of those remain on the disk like "Temporary Internet Files" in the Internet Explorer directory and occupy several gigabyte.

Has anyone encountered this behavior?
Should I change the component?

[EDIT]: The cause of this problem wosn't `TIdHTTP`, but `TDownloadURL`! (that I use for download from another server)

Comment: `TIdHTTP` does not create *ANY* files of its own, especially on an upload, so the issue has to be with something else in your app that is creating the files outside of Indy.

Comment: Before upload the files, I download them from another server. In this case I use `TDownloadURL`; it could be this?

Comment: that is a likely culprit. So why aren't you deleting the files after downloading them and then uploading them?

Comment: Ok, `TDownloadURL` is the culprit!. I delete the files I download, but not those generated as temporary internet files